# $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2 \sin^2 (y)}{x^2 + 2y^2}$ how to prove this limit doesn't exist

Tags: calculus

Question is in the title.

I tried approaching from $x$ axis, $y$ axis, $y=x$, $y=x^2$, $y=x^3$... they all go to 0 as $(x,y)\to 0$. But wolframalpha says it doesn't exist.. how??? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28x%2Cy%29+-%3E+%280%2C0%29+x%5E2sin%5E2%28y%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2y%5E2%29

Comment: I have the feeling that Wolfram Alpha answer is not correct and I agree with you. For me, the limit is zero. But, I can be wrong !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, consider the absolute value of this expression in the neighbourhood of origin:
$$ \left\vert \frac{x^2 \sin^2y}{x^2+2y^2} \right\vert \leqslant
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2}$$
Apply the following inequality: $x^2 + 2y^2 \geqslant 2\sqrt{ x^2 \cdot 2y^2}$ (Cauchy-Bunyakovsky really).
Then you get:

$$ \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2} \leqslant \frac{x^2y^2}{2\sqrt{2} \vert x \vert \vert y \vert} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \vert x \vert \vert y \vert$$
For me it seems that limit exists and is zero :)

**NOTE:**
Strictly speaking, I used inequality of form $a^2 + b^2 \geqslant 2ab$, which is just consequence of $(a-b)^2 \geqslant 0$. Also, it's just "rephrasing" of arithmetic-geometric mean inequality which is one of particular cases for mentioned Cauchy-Bunyakovsky.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: can you also do x^2+2y^2 > |y|, so x^2y^2/|y| = x^2y, which approaches 0 as (x,y)->(0,0) therefore the original limit approaches 0 by the squeeze theorem? new to this whole thing so i'm not sure haha

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have said that I used Squeeze theorem too :) Well, $x^2 + 2y^2 \geqslant 2y^2 \geqslant y^2$ seems valid. But in neighbourhood of zero, it's not true that $y^2$ greater than $\vert y \vert$. But you can stop at $x^2 + 2y^2 \geqslant y^2$ and apply Squeeze theorem. It's even simplier than mine!